# Slow processing data when exeucting query using cx_Oracle.Cursor

Tags: python, database, database-cursor

In python, I am executing a ORACLE sql query using:

```
cursor = conn.execute(TEMPLATE, {'var1':'value1', 'var2':'value2'})
```

where

conn is an oracle connection.

The above statement returns within 1,2 seconds. I then do:

```
fields = [d[0] for d in cursor.description]
[dict(izip(fields, row)) for row in cursor]
```

in order to transform the results int a list of dictionaries. And the 2nd statement ("for row in cursor...") gets stuck, as in, it runs seemingly indefinitely.

Now, this is running on our server on a remote box, if I run the same query on my local box, against the same database, everything returns in under 30 seconds, and there are only 200 rows from the cursor. How can this run for so long on a different box for only 200 rows in the results (note, the conn.execute() statement returns quickly too on the box)?

What else can I do to further investigate?